# Purple edge on black berry leaves

Tags: diseases, blackberry

[image: blackberry navaho]
[image: blackberry navaho]

Hi,

I recently bought a blackberry plant (Navaho) and was wondering if any one can help me work out what's going on with it. It has purple edges on all the leaves, one or two have larger purple patches that have started to turn orange.

UK zone 8 if that helps

Editted to include additional info:

I bought it from a garden centre where it was growing undercover but outside. Unfortunately, it's the first time I've bought plants so I didn't check the condition properly, so it may well have been like this before I took it home. It was in a fairly small pot, around 10', and I've since potted it up into a 15' pot

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming it wasn't like this when you bought it? Where is it growing now and where was it growing when you bought it, indoors, outdoors?

Comment: It might just be the smallness of the pots and the fact that wherever you got them from has probably had them most of the winter... where did you get them, online or at a nursery/garden centre?

Comment: @rob I bought it from a garden centre where it was growing undercover but outside. Unfortunately, it's the first time I've bought plants so I didn't check the condition properly, so it may well have been like this before I took it home.

Comment: @bamboo It was in a fairly small pot, around 10', and I've since potted it up into a 15' pot. If it's due to the small pot it was in, is it likely to improve over time?

Comment: yes, if that's been the problem, but they really will do better in the ground... raspberries like to spread their roots out fairly widely - if they were under cover when you bought them, and you put them straight outside on getting them home,if you had overnight cold temperatures, they will also have reacted to that. Just make sure the canes (stems) don't have any similarly coloured areas...

Comment: @Bamboo thanks. Stuck with containers for the short term but will look at planting it into the soil once I have a chance to sort the garden out. I will keep an eye on it for now.